# jq - escaping backslash in keyname

Tags: linux, jq

I have a a key with a \ in it and I can't seem to access it in using jq. Any help is appreciated.

```
$ cat /tmp/yo
{
  "kubectl.kubernetes.io\last-applied-configuration": "test"
}

$ cat /tmp/yo | jq .["kubectl.kubernetes.io\last-applied-configuration"]
parse error: Invalid escape at line 2, column 52
```

Comment: Need more quotes. Your `"`s are being eaten by the shell, not passed to `jq`.

Comment: The other thing is that your data just isn't valid JSON at all. Neither `jq` nor any other compliant parser will read it -- I'm curious, for that matter, how you **generated** it in the first place.

Comment: For instance, the Python JSON module given that same input file would emit `ValueError: Invalid \escape: line 2 column 25 (char 26)`

Comment: If you paste your "JSON document" into Chrome, it's a little more generous -- it just ignores the backslash altogether, making the key `kubectl.kubernetes.iolast-applied-configuration`. There's a reason sane people (ie. everyone outside the Windows world) use *forward* slashes as separators.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**This is not a valid JSON document.** Backslashes in JSON must be escaped to be included in literal strings. Report a bug against whichever tool generated this invalid content.

---

To include a backslash in JSON would instead look like:

```
{
  "kubectl.kubernetes.io\\last-applied-configuration": "test"
}
```

If you had such a valid document, you could then use:

```
jq '.["kubectl.kubernetes.io\\last-applied-configuration"]' </tmp/yo
```